# How to inject scripts to index html file in the generated index.html in dist/<appName>?

Tags: angular8, webpack-4, html-webpack-plugin, angular-cli-v8

I have an index html file and i need to inject some configuration based scrips in production/staging environments.

Workspace index.html

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

Generated index.html in dist/my-app through ng build

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="runtime-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
  <script src="polyfills-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
  <script src="styles-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>  
  <script src="vendor-es5.js" nomodule defer></script> 
  <script src="main-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
</body>
```

My Requirement:

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="script-staging.js"></script>
  <script src="runtime-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
  <script src="polyfills-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
  <script src="styles-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>  
  <script src="vendor-es5.js" nomodule defer></script> 
  <script src="main-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
</body>
```

I am using Angular 8 + Webpack with CLI. I've included custom-webpack.configuration.js pointed from angular.json. I'm trying to achieve this using HTMLWebpackPlugin.

Be informed that dynamic script loading is optional, means I will or will not inject that script.js in generated index.html that would be decided during build time. So injection of script in generated html has to be done during build time which I should happen through plugin of webpack.

Any help would be appreciated, struggling for some days.

Answer (score 0):

You can point full path from ./scr/script-staging.js in angular.json in script array of your app object.

Here shown:-

```
"styles": [
  "styles.scss"
],
// like this
"scripts": [
  "./src/script-staging.js"
]
```

After adding this line of code you should build your app again "ng build"/"ng build --prod" and hopefully if everything gone correct then it should add you file to index.html.

Comment: Thanks Priyanshu for your comments.But this is not going to help as let's say there are 100 clients using this application & there are some configurations specific to a client. So this configuration could be present for that particular client or it could not be present. So this configuration has to be checked at build time. Hence loading of this staging file has to be checked & included at build time.

Comment: @user1759426 This answer is telling you how to include the configuration at build time. Based on your comment, I think you mean it should be included at runtime. Is that what you mean (unless you're building a version for each client, in which case this answer can in fact help you)? Whatever the answer to this is, can you update your question to include those details?

Comment: @JoryGeerts: Agreed the answer of Priyanshu would help if I know that this script(script-staging.js) has to be included no matter what. Let's say before building I don't know whether the configurations for a client is present or not, during build I'll find out whether configuration is present or not & then load those configurations during build.I'm trying to use a webpack custom plugin to do that, for now I'm trying webpack plugin HTMLWebpackPlugin to achieve the same.

Comment: So, to clarify: you are building a different version for each client. If (for instance) *clientname*.js exists, you want it to be included, otherwise you don't want anything?

Comment: @JoryGeerts: Spot on